# Open CSV, sort a specific column and overwrite existing CSV

Tags: python, sorting, csv

I'm been stuck on this one for a while. I'm trying to open a csv, sort by severity (Critical, High, Medium, Low) then overwrite the existing file. I'd also like to ignore the first wrote or add a header row.

**Original CSV**

```
IP Address  Severity    Score
10.0.0.1    High        2302
172.65.0.1  Low         310
192.168.0.1 Critical    5402
127.0.0.1   Medium      1672`
```

**Modified/Sorted CSV**

```
IP Address  Severity    Score
192.168.0.1 Critical    5402
10.0.0.1    High        2302
127.0.0.1   Medium      1672 
172.65.0.1  Low         310
```

**Code**

```
import csv
crit_sev = "Critical"
high_sev = "High"
med_sev = "Medium"
low_sev = "Low"
reader = csv.reader(open('sample.csv', 'r'))
row=0
my_list = []
for row in reader:
    if row[1] == crit_sev:
        my_list.append(row)
    elif row[1] == high_sev:
        my_list.append(row)
    elif row[1] == med_sev:
        my_list.append(row)
    elif row[1] == low_sev:
        my_list.append(row)

writer = csv.writer(open("sample.csv", 'w'))
header = ['IP Address', 'Severity', 'Score']
writer.writerow([header])
for word in my_list:
    writer.writerow([word])
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: "or add a header row" - what exactly are you trying to say?

Comment: Why not just open the CSV in Excel or something and sort it there?

Comment: CSV == Comma Separated Values.  I don't see any commas in your file, so that's probably the first issue.  Is it perhaps tab separated or fixed format?  Fixed seems unlikely, because when the IP address 192.168.0.254 comes along, you're not going to have enough room.

The general idea is to read each record in, classify it according to severity, and store it away in a data structure.  Then when done, write the new data structure in order of severity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Python's `csv` library to do this as follows:

```
import socket     
import csv

severity = {"Critical" : 0, "High" : 1, "Medium" : 2, "Low" : 3}     

with open('sample.csv', 'rb') as f_input:
    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input)
    header = next(csv_input)
    data = sorted(csv_input, key=lambda x: (severity[x[1]], socket.inet_aton(x[0])))

with open('sample.csv', 'wb') as f_output:
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)
    csv_output.writerow(header)
    csv_output.writerows(data)
```

This preserves the existing header and sorts the entries based on the `severity` column. Next it also (optionally) sorts by IP address (which may or may not be useful to you) using [`socket.inet_aton()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html?highlight=aton#socket.inet_aton) to convert the IP address into a sortable number.

For example:

```
IP Address,Severity,Score
10.168.0.1,Critical,5402
192.168.0.1,Critical,5402
10.0.0.1,High,2302
127.0.0.1,Medium,1672
172.65.0.1,Low,310
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Here's a `pandas` solution:

```
import pandas as pd
# Read the CSV file
data = pd.read_csv('sample.csv')

# Configure the levels of severity
levels = pd.Series({"Critical" : 0, "High" : 1, "Medium" : 2, "Low" : 3})
levels.name='Severity'

# Add numeric severity data to the table
augmented = data.join(levels,on='Severity',rsuffix='_')

# Sort and select the original columns
sorted_df = augmented.sort_values('Severity_')[['IP Address', 'Severity','Score']]

# Overwrite the original file
sorted_df.to_csv('sample.csv',index=False)
```

Comment: Would you need to define the various levels, as they're words rather than numbers?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Theoretically, yes. But in this very case the order of severity happily matches the alphabetic order ('C' < 'H' < 'M' < 'L').

Comment: 'M' < 'L'? Really?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Oops... You've got me.

Comment: :) It'd probably be good to show how to define the levels regardless, as a match of that sort would just be an arbitrary coincidence anyway.